# Detecting empty input from the stdin

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner, stdin

I am trying to detect whether or not a line from the stdin is blank, and I am at a loss. The following is code I have been trying to use, but it is not detecting when the line is null and/or if it just has spaces. Anybody can help me to see what I am doing wrong?

```
public static String scanPrint(Scanner stdinSP) {
    String wordSP = null;
    while (stdinSP.hasNext()) {
        wordSP = stdinSP.next();
        wordSP.trim();
        if (wordSP.length() == 0) {
            out.println("fail");
            break;
        } else {
            out.println("success");
            break;              
        }
    }

    out.println(wordSP); //debug
    return wordSP;
}
```

And I can only use the following import statements:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
import static java.lang.String.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
```

Note it does have a working scanner in the main method.

Comment: `wordSP.trim();` => `wordSP = wordSP.trim();`

Comment: You can replace the `while` with an `if` and get rid of the `break` statements. @alfasin - you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
wordSP.trim();
```

to:

```
wordSP = wordSP.trim();
```

Full code:

```
 public static String scanPrint( )
 {
        Scanner stdinSP = new Scanner(System.in);
        String wordSP = null;

        while(true)
        {

            if((wordSP = stdinSP.nextLine().trim()).length() == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("fail");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("success");
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(wordSP); //debug
        return wordSP;
    }
```

Comment: I just tried this, but it did not change anything with the output.

Comment: @user2967087 move the debug printing to the beginning: `out.println(wordSP);`

Comment: I moved it to the beginning but it doesn't appear to do anything. I enter a space, and nothing happens it just moves to the nextline. When I enter a valid entry, it works as it is supposed to.

Comment: @user2967087 sounds like it works as it should be - what did you expect it to do ?

Comment: If wordSP == null, it should println "fail" and then break from the loop. Right now if I enter a space or just hit enter, it just continues to run the program and nothing is printed.

Comment: @user2967087 change the condition in the `while` to: `while(true)`

Comment: Isn't it already true?
    while(stdinSP.hasNext())
should return true if there is a next.

Comment: It did not work mate. When I input the proper input it came back as "fail" when it is supposed to be "success", and then when there is a space it does not do anything and instead just continues with the program as it was already.

Comment: When you press enter or click space/s and then press enter - it fails. If you enter a *real* input it succeeds. That's what you asked in your question: "...not detecting when the line is null and/or if it just has spaces"